# Error de uso de tabulacion y sangria

Tags: python, python-3.x

hoy hice un programa básico de practica el cual me lanza aun TabError la cual no entiendo ya que guardo muy bien  la identacion de 4 espacios o una tabulación ya revise y Conte espacios y al parecer todo anda en orden

```
class mascota:

def __init__(self,nombre,edad,sonido):


    self.nombre= nombre
    self.edad = edad
    self.respira= False
    self.comida= False
    self.sonido = sonido

def camnina(self):
    self.camina = True  


TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Comment: El problema es que, aunque **visualmente** todas las líneas están tabuladas la misma cantidad, **en realidad** no están tabuladas de la misma forma, sino que algunas usan el caracter <TAB> mientras que otras usan cuatro espacios. Python te deja elegir cuál de las dos modalidades prefieres, pero debes ser consistente en su uso (como mínimo dentro del mismo bloque). Revisa si tu editor tiene alguna opción para mostrarte los caracteres invisibles <TAB> y espacio y verás la diferencia. Revisa también si tiene alguna opción para que cuando pulses <tab>, inserte siempre cuatro espacios.

Comment: Tal como dice @abulafia, y como tú mismo dices: ***guardo muy bien la identacion de 4 espacios o una tabulación*** -> Nop nop nop noooop, no señor. Una tabulación **NO** es lo mismo que cuatro espacios, cuatro espacios son 4 caracteres de espacio, una tabulación es un caracter de tabulador, es lo mismo 4 limones que 1 pera? No, pues tampoco es lo mismo cuatro espacios que un tabulador. A python le da igual lo que uses para indentar, 2 espacios, 4, tabuladores... SIEMPRE QUE SEA CONSISTENTE. Eso es lo importante: ***CONSISTENCIA EN LA INDENTACIÓN***!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiene que tabular dentro de la clase, así:

```
class Mascota:
    def __init__(self,nombre,edad,sonido):
        self.nombre= nombre
        self.edad = edad
        self.respira= False
        self.comida= False
        self.sonido = sonido

    def camina(self):
        self.camina = True
```